# Real time update html contents when certain spreadsheet is modified

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there any way to update div content when spreadsheet changes?
That I'm looking for is like a chat and webSockets so without the need of updating and any timeout.

HTML file:

```
<div id="thediv"></div>
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showChange).setChangefromSpreadsheet();
function showChange(e){
$('#thediv').html(e); //of course jQuery called
}
```

.sg file

```
function setChangefromSpreadsheet()
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadsheetId')
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
return data[0][0];
}
```

This wil work with a timeout like 
(on the html file):
EDITED to setInterval:

```
setInterval(function(){google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(showChange).setChangefromSpreadsheet()}, 1000); //for example
```

Is there any way to do that without any timeout?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The reason is the possible limits of calls and good practice (I think). I'm sure I wont get the limits but... Performance of the app (on mobiles for example) could be lost with that kind of call (timeout)

Comment: You can set a field which will be a flag. It can be set to New or Old. You can then access this in your div as {{ $flag }}. You can have a css with <div-name>.{{ $flag }}. This will help you get your old and new divs. This can be in conjunction with your spreadsheet getting updated via your trigger. This is a short description. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you're looking for is not possible. You're looking for some sort of "trigger" where a message is sent from Google Apps to your web page whenever a Spreadsheet Edit occurs.

Technically the only way around this is what you are trying to avoid: having your web page check every x seconds. By the way, you would want to use `setInterval()`, not `setTimeout()` if you want it to run every x seconds and not just once.

I see why this looks ugly. But if you handle it well enough, there's really not anything wrong with `setInterval()` in this case. If it's running less frequent than once per second, you definitely won't run into any restrictions with Google's limits (I think you can run like 6 calls back to Google at once, which is plenty for what you're doing).

Alternatively, depending on your application, you could also have a "Refresh" button for the user to click. Not sure if that works in your case, but it technically is an option as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You understood well the question. I agree with almost all except the Google limits because in the case of a chat, for example, each user logged in will call recursively. If I have 200 users using the app at a time?  I think it could be a suggestion for Google Apps scripts team that they implement a script by default that establish a websocket with the server side, or an API to that. I think that's not very difficult for them (they just have it in Drive) and possibilities and performance would be very very much good. (Editing to setInterval)

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad setInterval works for you for now!